# passing flashvars and texting locally

Tags: flash, swfobject

Does flashvars work when testing locally? When I test it using swfObject V1.5 using a file saved for flash player 10 It doesn't seem to work. Can anyone confirm that this should work locally.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title>Screensaver</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">

    body {
        background-color: #ffffff;
    }

    #flashcontent {
        width: 100%x;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="flashcontent">
        <strong>You need to upgrade your Flash Player</strong>
        This is replaced by the Flash content. 
        Place your alternate content here and users without the Flash plugin or with 
        Javascript turned off will see this. Content here allows you to leave out <code>noscript</code> 
        tags. Include a link to <a href="swfobject.html?detectflash=false">bypass the detection</a> if you wish.
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var so = new SWFObject("screensaver.swf", "main", "100%", "100%", "10", "#ffffff");
        so.addVariable("rssFeedUrl", "campaign.xml");
        so.write("flashcontent");

    </script>   
</body>
</html>
```

Then in flash I have this.

```
var flashVars:Object=LoaderInfo(loaderInfo).parameters;

var rss = flashVars.rssFeedUrl;
```

Comment: Ok got it to work not exactly sure what the problem was.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried SWFObject 2.2 (the latest version) and the html worked locally with parameters passed without any issue.

I wonder why you would not move to the latest version of SWFObject.  In your case, the code would look like

```
swfobject.embedSWF(
                "screensaver.swf", "main", 
                "100%", "100%", 
                "10", "", 
                { rssFeedUrl: "compaign.xml" }, {}, {});
```